# Add custom fields to specific menus

Tags: custom-field, menus, wp-admin, hooks, admin-menu

How do I add custom fields to a specific menu?

For example, I have menu "Primary" with ID 13. How do I run the `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields` hook only if ID matches the currently selected menu?

I tried getting the ID from the `$id` parameter of the hook, but it always returns 0. I'm trying to check the ID like this:

```php
function add_menu_field( $item_id, $item, $depth, $args, $id ) {
    var_dump( $id );
}

add_action( 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields', 'add_menu_field', 10, 5 );
```

This returns `int(0)` but my nav menu ID is 13. Am I using this hook incorrectly, or is there another way to get the ID? My goal is to put custom fields on a specific nav by checking the ID.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Seems like you're looking for a generic PHP code like `if ( 13 === $id ) { // add your field }`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Yes but how can I compare `$id` if it always returns 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I using this hook incorrectly

No, you're not.

> is there another way to get the ID?

Yes, try this:

```php
function add_menu_field( $item_id, $item, $depth, $args, $id ) {
    $id2 = 0;

    if ( ! $id && isset( $_GET['menu'] ) && $_GET['menu'] ) {
        $id2 = absint( $_GET['menu'] );
    }
    elseif ( ! $id && ! isset( $_GET['menu'] ) ) {
        // Get recently edited nav menu.
        $id2 = absint( get_user_option( 'nav_menu_recently_edited' ) );

        if ( ! is_nav_menu( $id2 ) ) {
            $nav_menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
            $id2 = ( ! empty( $nav_menus ) ) ? $nav_menus[0]->term_id : 0;
        }
    }

    if ( 13 === $id2 && is_nav_menu( $id2 ) ) {
        echo '<hr>add your awesome custom field here';
    }
}
```

And that's basically how WordPress gets the ID on the `wp-admin/nav-menus.php` (Appearance → Menus) page — if there's no selected menu (`$_GET['menu']` is not set), we use the recently edited menu, if any; if none, we use the first menu in the available nav menus.

### Alternate Option (use a filter to add the action)

You can use [`wp_edit_nav_menu_walker`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_edit_nav_menu_walker/) to add your action to `wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields` whereby the action (i.e. the hook callback) would simply display the custom field. For example:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_edit_nav_menu_walker', 'wpse_378190', 10, 2 );
function wpse_378190( $class, $menu_id ) {
    $tag = 'wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields';
    if ( 13 === $menu_id && ! has_action( $tag, 'add_menu_field2' ) ) {
        add_action( $tag, 'add_menu_field2', 10, 5 );
    }

    return $class;
}

// This function is hooked to wp_nav_menu_item_custom_fields and fires only if the
// menu ID is 13. So no need to check the $id and just display your custom field.
function add_menu_field2( $item_id, $item, $depth, $args, $_id ) {
    $id = 13;
    echo '<hr>display your awesome custom field here';
}
```